# SSIS Count duplicates

Tags: ssis

I'm using SSIS and have a table like this:

```
Region    | Process      | Queue    | Col 1    | Col 2
----------------------------------------------------------
EMEA        ProcA          Q101       XXX        YYY
EMEA        ProcB          Q101       AAA        BBB
EMEA        ProcB          Q101       CCC        DDD
AMERICAS    ProcA          Q099       EEE        FFF
AMERICAS    ProcA          Q099       GGG        HHH
AMERICAS    ProcA          Q099       GGG        HHH
```

I want to add a column that counts the number of duplicates of Region, Process and Queue. The output should look like this:

```
Region    | Process      | Queue    | Col 1    | Col 2   | Count
----------------------------------------------------------------
EMEA        ProcA          Q101       XXX        YYY       1
EMEA        ProcB          Q101       AAA        BBB       1
EMEA        ProcB          Q101       CCC        DDD       2
AMERICAS    ProcA          Q099       EEE        FFF       1
AMERICAS    ProcA          Q099       GGG        HHH       2
AMERICAS    ProcA          Q099       GGG        HHH       3
```

I would prefer not to use SQL as this data is in the middle of a Data Flow and I'd have to write to SQL server to use SQL.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Currently I dont have SSIS in laptop, so only can give you a solution with image: use a flatfile to store four values: Region, Process, Queue and Sequence(Count), and everytime use script component to read file and get latest Sequence(Count), add 1 and add in Drive Column, and Update FlatFile.

Comment: How are you sorting these values?  Is there no column for the date/time of the row?

Comment: @iamdave yes, there is a date/time column (modified date/time).

Comment: In that case my answer will do what you need.  Please have a go and let us know how you get on.

Comment: @iamdave Yep, that worked - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing to a database somewhere, you will need to do this in a `Script Component`.  Because you want a row count within partitioned groups, you will need to sort your data before it gets to the script component, so that the data is ordered correctly.  To do this, you will need a column that defines the row chronology as well as your categories.

With the data sorted, your script component should take the categories as an input variable, which is referenced in the script to check if the current row is of the same category as the previous one.  If it is, incrememnt the row number and add to the output.  If it isn't, reset back to `1`.

You can see a guide on how to do this [here](http://dhinakaran-msbi.blogspot.com/2014/06/rownumber-using-ssis.html)

If you are using a very large file, be aware that the `sort` is a blocking transformation, which means that your data flow will be held up until it has finished reading in all the data.  This can have implications for memory usage and data flow run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Aggregate Transformation to get Row count, but make sure that the Source is sorted:

- [Aggregate Transformation in SSIS Basic Mode](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/aggregate-transformation-in-ssis/)
- [SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) - Aggregate (COUNT) Transformations Control in SSIS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ae35ca/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-aggregate-count-transformations-control-in-ssis/)

Comment: Both of these examples return less records than the starting recordset. I want to return all records and all columns. Unless I'm missing something :P